# Powershell to convert all lines of txt file to JSON format

Tags: json, powershell

I have output.txt file contains:

```
device:VM01,partition:"C",size_gb:100
device:VM02,partition:"D",size_gb:200
device:VM03,partition:"E",size_gb:150
```

I expect the result after I read each line and use ConvertTo-Json:

```
[
{
    "device": "VM01",
    "partition": "C",
    "size_gb": 100
},
{
    "device": "VM02",
    "partition": "D",
    "size_gb": 200
},
{
    "device": "VM01",
    "partition": "E",
    "size_gb": 150
}
]
```

but It returns:

```
"device:VM01,partition:\"C\",size_gb:100"
```

Update my code:

```
$source_file = ".\output.txt"
$text = (Get-Content -Path $source_file -ReadCount 0) -join "`n"
$text | ConvertTo-Json
```

How can I get that with PowerShell?

Comment: Please post the code that you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like that :

```
$FileContent = Get-Content C:\temp\stack.txt
$ArrayOfDevices = @()

Foreach ( $Line in $FileContent)
{

    $CurrentSplit = $Line.split(',')
    $CurrentDevice = $CurrentSplit[0].split(':')[1]
    $CurrentPartition = $CurrentSplit[1].split(':')[1].replace('"','')
    $CurrentSize = [int]$CurrentSplit[2].split(':')[1]

    $ArrayOfDevices +=  [pscustomobject]@{
        "device" = $CurrentDevice
        "Partition" = $CurrentPartition
        "Size_GB" = $CurrentSize
    }
}

$ArrayOfObjects | convertto-json
```

so , i get the file content
for each line i split with the comma separator, and then create a customobject. This object is stored in an array.
After the loop we convert the array to json.

But if you could change the format of the output.txt, to be a propred CSV this would make your life much easier.

Comment: Please read this: https://github.com/PowerShell/DscResources/blob/0a9d28fcc467dfe7609d29ad7122f3d2dd2b4586/StyleGuidelines.md. There is no official guideline for powershell scripts, yet it has some rules that should be followed for good readability based on .NET. Your script does not follow its own naming convention.

Comment: @LxLechat I converted CSV format to a,b,c in output.txt because I thought It's easier to use ConvertTo-Json

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generalized solution based on [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv), which doesn't rely on hard-coded column/property names or specific ordering of columns. Note the use of [intrinsic member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members) `.psobject.Properties` to reflect on the properties (columns) of the objects output by `Import-Csv`.

Note that the code assumes that your `output.txt` CSV files does have a header row, even though you're not showing it in the sample data. If it really doesn't have a header row, use `-Header a,b,c` to supply (dummy) column names.

```
Import-Csv output.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $oht = [ordered] @{} # Create an aux. (ordered) hashtable.
    # Loop over the column values, split them into name and value,
    # and add them to the aux. hashtable.
    foreach ($prop in $_.psobject.Properties.Value) {
        # Split into name and value, and remove enclosing double quotes.
        $name, $val = $prop.Split(':').Trim('"')
        # If the value can be interpreted as an integer, convert it to one.
        if ($val -as [int]) { $val = [int] $val }
        $oht[$name] = $val  # Add an entry.
    }
    $oht # Output the hashtable for processing by ConvertTo-Json
} | ConvertTo-Json
```